# Why SAM rule doesn't work on parameterless method

Tags: scala, anonymous-class

```
// ok
val sam0: MySamWithEmptyParameter = () => 100

// doesn't work
//  val sam1: MySamWithParameterless = () => 100

trait MySamWithEmptyParameter {
  def receive(): Int
}

trait MySamWithParameterless {
  def receive: Int
}
```

Why sam1 fails to override the receive method? The scalac compile both of traits to same code.

```
abstract trait TestSAM$MySamWithEmptyParameter extends Object {
  def receive(): Int
};

abstract trait TestSAM$MySamWithParameterless extends Object {
  def receive(): Int
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SI-10555](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10555) talks exactly about this. This was a simple design decision to only support an explicit empty parameter list, even though the two compile down to an empty parameter list anyway.

[The relevant part of the Specification says](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#sam-conversion) (emphasis mine):

> - the method m **must have a single argument list**;

This is indeed a bit awkward as eta expansion does work for methods with an empty parameter list.

### Edit

Contacted the guys at Lightbend. Here is a response by Adrian Moors, Scala team lead:

> The original reason was to keep the spec simple, but perhaps we should revisit. I agree it’s surprising that it works for `def a(): Int`, but not in your example.
>
> Internally, methods that don’t define an argument list at all, and those that do (even if empty) are treated differently. 
>   This has led to confusion/bugs before — to name just one: https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/284.
>
> In 2.13, we’re reworking eta-expansion (it will apply more aggressively, but ()-insertion will happen first). We’ve been back and forth on this, but the current thinking is:
>
> - 0-ary methods are treated specially: if the expected type is sam-equivalent to Function0, we eta-expand; otherwise, `()` is inserted (in dotty, you are required to write the () explicitly, unless the method is java-defined) — I’m still not sure about whether we should ever eta-expand here
> - for all other arities, a method reference is eta-expanded regardless of the expected type (if there’s no type mismatch, this could hide errors when you refactor a method to take arguments, but forget to apply them everywhere. However, since functions are first-class values, it should be easy to construct them by simplify referring to a method value).
>
> The upshot is that we can deprecate method value syntax (`m _`), since it’s subsumed by simply writing `m`. (Note that this is distinct from placeholder syntax, as in `m(, _)`.)
>   (See also the thread around this comment: https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2570#issuecomment-306202339)